# sw-media-field vs. sw-media-upload-v2 and upload to a specific folder

Tags: shopware, shopware6

According to shopware staff and the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/testing/store/quality-guidelines-plugins#own-media-folder) in a plugin we have to create an upload field, which then uses a media folder we created with the plugin installation or a folder that the customer created.

With the [sw-media-field](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-plugin-configuration#media-selection) this is not possible, as far as i could find out and with the sw-media-upload-v2 we are struggling to get it uploading to the folder we created as well.

Is there any example or documentation how to do this right?

What we are trying to do here is to upload an image additionally to an existing entity. The saving poart and all works well, the adding via entity extension also, but the upload to a specific folder we are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

The `defaultFolder` property of `sw-media-upload-v2` takes the name of an entity assigned to a default folder.

For instance there's a `media_folder` entity with the name "Product Media". This entity has an association to another entity `media_default_folder` which in turn has a field `entity` with the value `'product'`. This is to denote that this folder should primarily contain media elements that belong to `product` entities. If you wanted your `sw-media-upload-v2` instance to assign media to a specific folder, you can refer to the entity of its default folder.

```html
<sw-media-upload-v2
    default-folder="myCustomEntity"
/>
```

Example payload when you persist your custom media folder:

```php
$this->mediaFolderRepository->create([
    [
        // ...
        'defaultFolder' => [
            'entity' => 'myCustomEntity',
            'associationFields' => ['associatioName'],
        ],
    ],
], $context);
```

Where `associatioName` would be the name of the association in the definition of your custom entity to the `media` entity.